# GeoServer WMS XML request with NamedLayer filter

Tags: geoserver, sld, filter, xml

I need to draw a map with some custom features I don't have in database. I found SLD query that allows me to do that (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/data/release/demo/WMS_getMap_inlineFeatureSmile.xml), but I also need to filter out some features from other layers I want to draw. Here is my XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ogc:GetMap xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ows" 
            xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
            version="1.2.0"
            service="WMS">
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
                         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
                         xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
                         xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <NamedLayer>
            <Name>pipes</Name>
            <LayerFeatureConstraints>
                <FeatureTypeConstraint>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>gid</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                </FeatureTypeConstraint>
            </LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <NamedStyle>
                <Name>pipes</Name>
            </NamedStyle>
        </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescrtiption>
    <!-- bbox & output -->
</ogc:GetMap>
```

but it still renders all features, not the one I need. It seems to not even parse this filter, because it doesn't react to typos. Primary keys are exposed in GeoServer settings.

I've done that using this schema description: https://www.mediamaps.ch/ogc/schemas-xsdoc/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor_xsd.html

GeoServer version: 2.17.0

//EDIT

I'm sending this XML as POST body on url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms, I receive image with rendered map, but features are not filtered (should only one be rendered). I've tried also with other Filters and other layers, none works, doesn't even react on wrong property name (should throw exception) or invalid structure (wrong tag name, missing element). XML seems to be correct, according to https://www.mediamaps.ch/ogc/schemas-xsdoc/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor_xsd.html.

Comment: can you check (and [edit] the question to confirm) that you meet all the requirements of [library mode SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/working.html#library-mode)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Added additional information. I'm sure the requirements are met, layer renders, but doesn't filter features.

Comment: We need to see the full actual request to be sure you meet library mode - nothing will work if you don't